# Unexpected behavior with `block.timestamp` in truffle test

Tags: solidity, truffle, evm, blocks, truffle-test

I am doing some experiments with `block.timestamp`(which is `now`'s alias).
I wrote some code to see if `block.timestamp` really represents the timestamp of the last mined block.

From the [documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.23/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties):

> *block.timestamp (uint): current block timestamp as seconds since unix epoch*

Below code is expected to return the timestamp of the last mined block(since it's just a call, not a transaction), but it seems to be returning the "current timestamp" which is unexpected.

(in solidity contract, tested with solidity v0.4.23):

```
function test() public view returns(uint, uint) {
    return (block.timestamp, block.number);
}
```

(in truffle js test case, tested with truffle v4.1.7):

```
it("test", async function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        console.log(await contractInstance.test())
        await sleep(1000)
    }
})
```

Sample output with `truffle test` command:

```
[ { [String: '1524691464'] s: 1, e: 9, c: [ 1524691464 ] },
{ [String: '166'] s: 1, e: 2, c: [ 166 ] } ]
[ { [String: '1524691465'] s: 1, e: 9, c: [ 1524691465 ] },
{ [String: '166'] s: 1, e: 2, c: [ 166 ] } ]
[ { [String: '1524691466'] s: 1, e: 9, c: [ 1524691466 ] },
{ [String: '166'] s: 1, e: 2, c: [ 166 ] } ]
[ { [String: '1524691467'] s: 1, e: 9, c: [ 1524691467 ] },
{ [String: '166'] s: 1, e: 2, c: [ 166 ] } ]
[ { [String: '1524691468'] s: 1, e: 9, c: [ 1524691468 ] },
{ [String: '166'] s: 1, e: 2, c: [ 166 ] } ]
[ { [String: '1524691469'] s: 1, e: 9, c: [ 1524691469 ] },
{ [String: '166'] s: 1, e: 2, c: [ 166 ] } ]
```

On the other hand, when I manually call the js function using the web3 interface in the browser(`contractInstance.methods.test().call()`), it works as expected.

Sample output:

```
p {0: "1524690793", 1: "157"}
p {0: "1524690793", 1: "157"}
p {0: "1524690793", 1: "157"}
p {0: "1524690793", 1: "157"}
p {0: "1524690793", 1: "157"}
p {0: "1524690793", 1: "157"}
p {0: "1524690793", 1: "157"}
```

So why is this? What's the catch when I call the function in truffle test? Any ideas?

*Note: I've created a [repo](https://github.com/vzts/block-timestamp-test) for this. If you would like to test, you can simply run `truffle test` after setting up local mining node(e.g.ganache).*

Comment: Doesn't seem weird to me. JavaScript can't handle large integers like Solidity can, so Web3 and Truffle use BigNumber objects to represent them. [Check out the docs](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/)

Comment: @Henk I'm not saying it's weird because the uint return type gets converted to string or to big number. It's weird because the timestamp value increases in truffle test! Do you have any idea what's going on?

Comment: I just tried your contract and for me this works just fine, so I'd say this is not related to your code but to ganache/truffle? I was using TestRPC v6.0.3 and truffle v4.1.7.

Comment: @KaiKälberer Oh really? That's weird though... Did you run `truffle test` for testing?

Comment: Yes - cloned the repo, started testrpc and ran `truffle test`.

Comment: @KaiKälberer Thanks a lot for sharing the result! I should have a try on my own with other rpcs. Looks like it's an issue with the interface between truffle test and the ganache then.

Comment: @KaiKälberer It really was the problem with ganache..! I will file an issue on ganache repo. Thanks again.

Comment: I guess what I learned by now is that you always should try to check on a "real rpc" if you are unsure about the behaviour there. it mostly comes down to testrpc, ganache, ... :) happy to have helped!